# I am facing problem during installing reactjs, when I do "npm start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

C:\Users---\Desktop\my\demo>'''npm start'''

> demo@0.1.0 start C:\Users---\Desktop\my\demo 
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.56.1/ 
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\91963\Desktop\my\demo\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:291
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT 
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19) 
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at: 
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn cmd',
path: 'cmd',
spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! demo@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the demo@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users---\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-15T07_26_30_566Z-debug.log

Comment: can you delete your node_modules folder and install again and try npm start ?

Comment: I did it many time but still same problem

Comment: can you add your package.json content here ?

Comment: Packege.json   {
  "name": "my",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Comment: package.json is incomplete!

Comment: So what I have to do?

Comment: This could not be the full package.json. You are giving cmd ```npm start``` to run a web application but this is not defined in package.json. Maybe you shared any other json file.